# Writing the product $\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^r}{r!} \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-s}}{s!}$ as a power series in $z$

Tags: summation, power-series

My lecturer states that the product

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^r}{r!} \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-s}}{s!}$$

can be written as (with $n = r-s$)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\sum_{r=n}^\infty \frac{1}{r!(r-n)!} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} z^n \sum_{r=n}^\infty \frac{1}{r!(r-n)!}$$

but I just don't understand how this has happened. Can someone do the algebra step by step please?

This is my attempt:

Set $n=r-s$ then we have $s = r-n$ and

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^r}{r!} \sum_{r-n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-r+n}}{(r-n)!} = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{n=r}^\infty \frac{z^{n}}{r!(r-n)!}$$

Comment: This is simply regrouping every contribution $z^{r-s}$ such that $r-s=n$, for each $n$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Did I have edited the question with my attempt. Why has his outer sum got $n$ and inner sum got $r$?

Comment: Right, so the change of variables in the indices is from $(r,s)$ with $r\geqslant0$, $s\geqslant0$ to $(r,n)$ with $n=r-s$, that is, to $(r,n)$ with $r\geqslant0$, $n\leqslant r$, or, equivalently, to $(r,n)$ with $n$ in $\mathbb Z$, $r\geqslant\max(n,0)$. Thus, the double sum is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=n}^\infty \frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}.$$ Note the mistake in the claim in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution in the form requested**:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{z^r}{r!}\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{z^{-s}}{s!}
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{z^{r-s}}{r!s!}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{n=r-\infty}^r\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}
&&\text{putting $n=r-s$}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty}^r\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}+\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^r\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}&&\text{splitting ranges}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=n}^\infty\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}
&&\text{swapping ordering order of summation}\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=n}^\infty\frac{z^n}{r!(r-n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}z^n\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{r!(r-n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\sum_{r=n}^\infty \frac{1}{r!(r-n)!}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

**Solution posted earlier**:

The [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two infinte series is given by:
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty f(r) \sum_{s=0}^\infty g(s)=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^k f(l)g(k-l)\\
$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\overbrace{\frac{z^r}{r!}}^{f(r)}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \overbrace{\frac{z^{-s}}{s!}}^{g(s)}&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^k \frac{z^l}{l!}\frac{z^{-(k-l)}}{(k-l)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{l=0}^kz^{2l}\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{l=0}^kz^{2l}\binom kl\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-k}}{k!}(1+z^2)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(z+\frac1z)^k}{k!}\\
&=e^{z+\frac 1z}\qquad\blacksquare 
\end{align}$$

---

In this particular case, it would have been more straightforward to evaluate the summations individually and then multiply them i.e. 
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^r}{r!}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-s}}{s!}
=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^r}{r!}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(z^{-1})^s}{s!}
=e^z \cdot e^{\frac 1z}=e^{z+\frac 1z}$$

Comment: Hi. You haven't answered my question.. I asked for a specific form. Not the closed form of the series. I started from the function $e^{z+1/z}$ and have been asked to find the general $c_n$ in its Laurent expansion.

Comment: Edited to address your specific request.